# Sending arraylist to controller via ajax

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a certain array list in my jquery which I would like to send to my controller..

```
var selectedNodesArray = [];
            var selectedNodesList = $('#JsTreeId').jstree("get_selected", true);
            $.each(selectedNodesList, function () {
                selectedNodesArray.push(this.text);
            });
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/Home/Test",                    
           data: JSON.stringify({ selectedNodesArray: selectedNodesArray })
       });
```

My controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Test(string[] selectedNodesArray)
 {
 }
```

I've tried using above method of JSON.stringify, but the value in controller shows null when it comes to post method....
Help me know how to send an array list from ajax to controller....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set ContentType and DataType in ajax call.
update your ajax code like below:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/Home/Test/",
        data: JSON.stringify({ selectedNodesArray: selectedNodesArray }), 
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
 });
```